# Angular ng-repeat вывод значений в ряд

Tags: css, angularjs, веб-дизайн

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода значений массива обьектов в ряд. Вот пример кода:

```
<div id="catBlock">
    <div ng-style="catBlock" ng-repeat="cat in list | orderBy: 'id' ">
                <img width="120px" height="150px" src='{{cat.imgPath}}' title="{{cat.name}}"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.catBlock = {
    "display": "inline",
    "clear": "both",
    "border": "1px solid #666666",
    "background": "#555555",
    "width": "165px",
    "height": "210px"
};
```

Вывод происходит стандартно в столбик
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать для того что бы список выводился в ряд, а не в столбик?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

---

***PS/ Есть предположение что этого обычным CSS не решить и вероятно придется изврашаться с repeat and if.***

Comment: Не воспроизводится Ваша проблема: https://plnkr.co/edit/8BVa8SvNnXgQM4ngJAgl
Давайте минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Весьма - Странно. Сейчас попытаюсь перепроверить и выложить что бы воспроизводило... Спасибо

Comment: Перепроверил, кстати вот выложил https://plnkr.co/edit/RjSy6R9ncpzduu2OK3oB (там есть пару коментов). И что самое удивительное то все прекрасно работает. и вывод идет в ряд, только если поставить значение _**display:block**_ тогда в столбец. Ну так, а у меня же в коде то  _**display:inline**_  !!! и не могу найти где именно перекрывает _display:block_ , есть предположение, что  это автоматический добавочный класс ng-scope который появляется после компиляции. Так ему тоже я жестко прописывал display:inline. Кстати проект на Java, SpringBoot, Angular.

Comment: И это все на, сервере, Tomcat-8.5.3 Либы тяну мавеном вот так:
`       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
`

Comment: В общем то нашел я проблему она оказалась в настройке стилей CSS. После того как убил все собственные стили вывод пошел как и хочется - в ряд. осталось дело за малым переписать CSS. Хотя для начала все же поищу в каком блоке его блокировало ...
PS/ спасибо за быстрый отклик ...

Comment: Так по идее в инструментах браузера можно же посмотреть, какие стили применяются к элементу, и откуда они берутся.

Comment: Вы правы, 100% - Можно, и я видел, что _**display:block**_, вот только полагал, что он прирос автоматом, от автоматически добавляемого класса ng-scope. Ну, а потом уже нашел, "очень хорошо" поискав нашел что в одном из классов, как то странно наследовался стиль для _<a>_, что `clear:both; display:inline;`  не срабатывало. В общем то, вернул назад CSS - переписал пару классов, а также, что, _**важно**_, прописал **_display:inline-block_** и "о чудо", оно начало работать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем то нашел я проблему она оказалась в настройке стилей CSS. После того как убил все собственные стили вывод пошел как и хочется - ***в ряд***. осталось дело за малым переписать CSS. Хотя для начала все же поищу в каком блоке его блокировало ...